# What is exactly a Dobsonian, and what are the differences when compared with Schmidt-Cassegrain or Newtonian?

Tags: astronomy, telescopes

What is exactly a [Dobsonian telescope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobsonian_telescope), and what are the differences between this technical choice over a [Schmidt-Cassegrain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt%E2%80%93Cassegrain_telescope) or a [Newtonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_telescope) configurations?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It should be asked in Astronomy SE

Comment: @GiorgioP, I agree, but right now it's (still) on topic here. Check [this Meta discussion](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13227/75633). Besides, it's too old to migrate, so I'm forced to vote to leave it open now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dobsonian is a type of mount, whereas Schmidt-Cassegrain and Newtonian are different configurations of the optics inside the telescope.  Dobsonian mounted telescopes are almost always Newtonian due to the Newt's ideal placement of the eyepiece.

This is a Dobsonian mounted Newtonian scope:

[image: Dobsonian telescope]

A Dobsonian mount does not track the stars as they move in the sky, so it's not suitable for some applications but it's a great "looking around" mount and is really easy to use.  I've set people at my Dob before and they intuitively get it within a few minutes.  My German equatorial on the other hand takes a good deal of expertise to use.

Dobs are great for large or heavy scopes because they effectively balance the scope so that moving the scope requires very little effort.

Comment: did you build it yourself ?

Comment: I did not, no.  Maybe one of these days I'll build myself a 24" or something nice and big.  Right now I have an 8" Orion SkyQuest.  It's just the right size to be a big hit at star parties!

Comment: The idea of a Dobsonian is to spend all the money on the mirror and build the simplest possible mount - so giving you the most photons/$

Comment: While tracking with a dobsonian isn't as 'natural' as doing so with other types of mounts:  Orion sells dobs with tracking/goto systems suitable for visual observation but not long exposure imaging.  Aftermarket kits are available for some other brands as well.

Answer (score 9):

Technically, a Dobsonian is a type of mount: an altazimuth (up/down, left/right) mount with large bearings and no slow motion controls or locks.  The large bearings make its operation smooth and, as a result, it has no need for slow motion controls or locks.

Any type of telescope can be mounted on a Dobsonian mount, but most commonly it supports large Newtonian reflectors, with apertures from 6- to 40-inches.  Because it doesn't need counterweights, it is very light in weight for its size, so that even the largest Dobsonian reflectors are portable.